# React Hooks Form Handling: Update the state of an object with multiple string items and one array item

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, user-input, setstate

I'm learning React using hooks to make an application. I've been following a tutorial however I would like to make some changes to it. I have an object with multiple string items and one array item:

```
  const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState({
    title: '',
    description: '',
    ingredients: [],
    instructions: '',
    tags: 'none'
  });
```

The tutorial originally had all string items so the following code worked perfectly to update the state:

```
    setRecipe({ ...recipe, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
```

Example of one of the input fields which were all were similar.

```
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='Title'
            name='title'
            value={title}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
```

Now that i've changed one of the items to an array, it no longer works. I've tried several ways to do it, for example:

```
 const [test, setTest] = useState({
    ingredients: ['bread', 'milk', 'honey']
  });

 const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  const updateQuery = e => {

    setQuery(e.target.value);
  };

  const addItem = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setTest(test => ({ ingredients: [...test.ingredients, query] }));
  };

return (

          <div>
            <button className='btn btn-light btn-block' onClick={addItem}>
              Add ingredient
            </button>
            <input
              type='text'
              placeholder='Description'
              name='ingredients'
              value={ingredients}
              onChange=(updateQuery)
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            {test.ingredients.map(data => (
              <ul key={data}>{data}</ul>
            ))}
          </div>

  );
```

I'm struggling to find a solution.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: This line hasn't fired an error that your test variable has been already declared ? `setTest(test => ({ ingredients: [...test.ingredients, query] }));`

Comment: Maybe it is good explain what are you trying to achieve with this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you provided needs some formatting (aka: `onChange={onChange}` rather than `onChange` and your input value to have `query` rather than ingredients)

Also, you were not retaking the old state when editing it.

I added to your state a non array integer field

```
const [test, setTest] = React.useState({
    nonArray: 0,
    ingredients: ["bread", "milk", "honey"]
  });
```

And then I changed you addItem to look like:

```
const addItem = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTest(old => ({ ...old, ingredients: [...old.ingredients, query] }));
    setQuery("");
  };
```

And it seems to be working like a charm.

Please check this [working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-gould-cbzow) that contains basically your code.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you need use useCallback in addItem, updateQuery like

```js
const updateQuery = useCallback(e => {

    setQuery(e.target.value);
  },[]);

const addItem = useCallback(e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setTest(test => ({ ingredients: [...test.ingredients, query] }));
  },[query]);
```

It is hooks principle, if you want to understand this principle, you can search `Principle of useCallback`.

If you want to know easy way, I can tell you one thing.
In when render component, `addItem` has query -> state change -> but addItem's query can't change

Comment: His problem isn't with memoization since recerating function is equivalent to having a usecallback with no deps

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line: `setTest(test => ({ ingredients: [...test.ingredients, query] })`

When working with react class components it would have been fine to set the state without spreading the entire previous state like `this.setState({ ingredients: [...test.ingredients, query] })` because internally react already merges your new object you pass into `this.setState` with the previous state.

In react hooks, `React.useState` doesn't do the merging so you have to merge the previous state like `setState(test => ({ ...test, ingredients: [...test.ingredients, query] })`.

edit: Also you declared the variable `test` at the top of your component. I recommend to rename the `test` argument inside `setTest` to something else.

Comment: Have you checked my answer before answering ? ‍♂️